# How to refer to column that is not in index?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame like this.

```
             Max         Min            Open     OpenA
Date                
2017.10.18  1.18050 1.17858 1.17872 1.18028
2017.10.19  1.18575 1.17676 1.17804 1.18565
2017.10.20  1.18575 1.17621 1.17642 1.18532
2017.10.23  1.17770 1.17245 1.17281 1.17763
2017.10.24  1.17924 1.17423 1.17430 1.17866
```

And i want to refer to the data['Date'] column. But i get this error:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Cheers!

Comment: `Date` is an index here, so use `df = df.reset_index()` and access `Date` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reset_index` and then treat it as a column:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['date']
```

OR

you can use `df.index.tolist()`. This will return you the values.

Ex:

```
In [2918]: df
Out[2918]: 
            emp_id
date              
10/1/2018  staff_1
10/1/2018  staff_2
10/1/2018  staff_3

In [2922]: df.index.tolist()
Out[2922]: ['10/1/2018', '10/1/2018', '10/1/2018']
```

OR

```
In [2924]: df = df.reset_index()
In [2926]: df['date']
Out[2926]: 
0    10/1/2018
1    10/1/2018
2    10/1/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't actually a `column`, rather `index`. So use `data.index` to fetch the values without changing current structure of the dataframe.

You can further use `data.reset_index()` to make it a column.

Note - Don't use `data.reset_index(drop=True)` as that will drop the current index without even making it a column.